# Creating variants for programming APIs in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, variants

I am kinda new to gradle… I created a Java API (now a Gradle project which builds an jar) a long time ago which has some sensitive parts responsible for unencrypting company data as well as some non sensitive stuff.  I have a new project that requires part of this API and naturally I don´t want to give away the whole API to other developers/contractors.

Ideally what I would like to do is create two variants, (lets say "Pro" and "Lite" for arguments sake - a simple product line approach I guess).

Is it possible to use gradle to build two different jars?
1. One which is the Pro full API
2. One which is the Lite API stripped of the relevant classes.

I see some mention of "flavours" on the net but seems all the hits are to do with Android development and properties.

The worse case scenario is that I create a new project containing just the needed code, but if I add new features/bug fixes to the API I wouldn't get the benefits of having them consolidated in a single project.

Another way could be to structure the existing project into different projects and have the security related stuff (both I/O and model) as a different jar.

Many thanks to anyone who can shed some light here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single Gradle project can produce any number of JARs. You could simply add another Jar task and give it a unique classifier to distinguish it from the "standard" library.

```
task jarLite(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'lite'
    exclude '**/SomeProprietaryCode.class'
    with jar
}
```

Comment: Also another (and probably better) option would be to utilize [source sets](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:source_sets)

Comment: Great Mark, I reckon this is the way to go! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could split it into a multi module project with a pro and lite version. When you build, you can publish the binaries for both pro and lite to your artifact repository (nexus, artifactory, etc), and then you would have 2 separate jars. For the common code, you could have a 3rd module that has stuff shared between the 2 and both the lite and pro could depend on it.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  I was considering exactly this approach but I was wondering if something more specific could be done without having to refactor stuff.  Seems Mark's answer with the exclude option is the way to go. Thanks though!

Comment: Be careful though not to exclude classes you actually need to run. You can do that mistakenly since you're excluding the class files after they're compiled, so this can be a little dangerous.

Comment: In my case there is a nice separation of concerns so I can exclude all from certain packages and hopefully be fine (the API isn't so big so I have full overview).  In fact my ´lite´variant only uses about 10-15 classes all told.   I am going to give to a try when I get some time next week.